# javascript library prototype functions not executing one after the other

Tags: prototype, javascript

I am working on a javascript library. here is the basic code:

```
(function(){
        var int,
            method,
            Jist = function(s){
                return new Jist.fn.init(s);
            };
        Jist.fn = Jist.prototype ={
            init : function(s){
                if(!s){
                    return this;
                }
                else{
                    this.length = 1;
                    if (typeof s === "object"){
                        this[0] = s;
                    }
                    else if(typeof s === "string"){
                        var obj;
                        obj = document.querySelectorAll(s);
                        this[0] = obj;
                        this.elem = this[0];
                    }
                    return this;
                }
            },
        }
        Jist.fn.init.prototype = Jist.fn;
        Jist.fn.init.prototype = {
            print : function(txt){
                for(var i=0; i<this.elem.length; i++) {
                    this.elem[i].innerHTML = txt;
                }
                return this;
            },
            click : function(callback){
                for(var i=0; i<this.elem.length; i++) {
                    this.elem[i].addEventListener("click",callback,false);
                }
                return this;
            },
            fadeOut : function(ms) {
                var elem = this.elem;
                var opacity = 1,
                    interval = 50,
                    gap = interval / ms;
                function func() { 
                    opacity -= gap;
                    for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
                        elem[i].style.opacity = opacity;
                    }
                    if(opacity <= 0) {
                        window.clearInterval(fading); 
                        for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++){
                            elem[i].style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    }
                }
                var fading = window.setInterval(func, interval);
                return this;
            },
            fadeIn : function(ms) {
                var opacity = 0,
                    interval = 50,
                    gap = interval / ms,

                    elem = this.elem;
                    for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++){
                        elem[i].style.display = 'block';
                        elem[i].style.opacity = opacity;
                    }
                function func() { 
                    opacity += gap;
                    for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++){
                        elem[i].style.opacity = opacity;
                    }
                    if(opacity >= 1) {
                        window.clearInterval(fading);
                    }
                }
                var fading = window.setInterval(func, interval);
                return this;
            }
        };
        window.Jist = window.jist = window.Jis = window.jis = window.Jit = window.jit = window._ = Jist;
})();
```

And here is what I have in my body section to test out the library:

```
<div id="fader"></div>
<input type="button" id="inpt" value="click"></input>
<script>
jist("#inpt").click(function(){
    jist("#fader").print("FooBar").fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).print("");
});
</script>
```

The line, `jist("#fader").print("FooBar").fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).print("");` is supposed to put the text "FooBar" in the div(which it does) then fade out, then fade in and wipe the text from the div.

But instead what happens is it begins fading out, then quickly tries to fadein. That is because all the functions are executing at the same time instead of one after the other.

Does anyone know how I can change my library so that happens? This is a jQuery-like library so I would like it to work similar to query.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery directly? Or at least have a look at their code? In jQuery, every DOM element has an animation queue attached in which you can insert operations to-be-executed.

Comment: Of course they are executing at the same time cos you call them at the same time

Comment: @lombausch This is a jquery based library and in jquery, you can call functions at the same time with them still executing dynamically.

Comment: in jquery, when using for example fadein fadeout, you would use callbacks. Otherwise it would execute asynchronously as well.

Comment: @lombausch Ok, I see, can I make a callback just blank code like this: `jist().fadeOut(1000,function(){}).fadeIn(1000,function(){})`?

Comment: nope that wouldn't work. 1.)  you must place your second as a callback of your first and 2) you must call it of course. google "JS callbacks"

Comment: @lombausch Hmm, I am not sure how I would do that, I have tried implementing a callback and the same thing happens. Are there any examples you could show me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into your long code but here is the short example how you should be doing it

```
// this is how you do it
m1.myFirst().mySecond();

//this is via callback
m2.myFirst(function(){
    m2.mySecond();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MfJQh/)